# Xbox Video-style Video Slider

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there an easy way to implement an Xbox Video-style slider in a Windows 8 app? For example, open up the Xbox Video app on Windows 8, and play any video. The slider has a finger-sized circle on a thin line, and the circle moves to the bottom of the line when you click/tap it.

I haven't actually started coding anything, I'm just curious if this is an openly copyable thing or if I would have to recreate it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fairly simple, though probably requiring some work to get it just right. You might get some pointers if you specified which language you were planning on using. If XAML is your thing, then you could use a RenderTransform and RenderTransformOrigin to rotate the circle and translate the slider.